# jQuery validate only if non-blank

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm on the latest jQuery version 1.6.2 and validate 1.8. What's the syntax for verifying a an optional phone field if non-blank? This doesn't trigger it

```
<%= f.text_field :fax, :class => "phoneUS" %>
```

It only gets triggered if I add `required` to `class` like such

```
<%= f.text_field :fax, :class => "required phoneUS" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the required class so that it is optional.
use the [minlength](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/minlength) equals 1 to check if its not empty.

```
<%= f.text_field :fax, :class => "phone", :minlength => "1" %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that didn't trigger the check

Comment: Actually that worked but with a couple of changes. Your example has `required`, that needs to be removed and there is an error in my example, I need to use `phoneUS` instead of `phone`. Corrected my example above.

Comment: cool ... i mentioned it in the answer ... but forgot to remove the required from class. Modified the answer as well by removing the required.